# Alternative to schema builder?

Tags: permissions, object, schema-builder

We have a data management group who need to review data structure since they are usually tasked with any historical data conversion/cleanup for any apps that move to Salesforce.

They asked for access to Schema Builder to easily see the structure and relationships after they had heard about this tool.

Apparently you have to grant "Customize Application" to enable Schema Builder for their account, [this is kinda crazy due to the privileges they receive](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000194001&language=en_US). So, I'm really not wanting to do that.

I noticed there is a "Idea" out there around this, but has fairly low votes, so an official change is probably years away..

My question is what alternatives has anyone in the same boat used to allow the same easy visual access to the object structure? Without giving them the keys to the kingdom, ideally.

Answer (score 1):

If the use case is to view the schema (As I understand from your question), you can install one of the many apps from AppExchange and provide the team access for that.

The one app I can find is [ERD TOOL](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003KNErEAO). It gives schema builder type UI.

I am not affiliated with this tool and I am not the developer for this tool. I recommend this as it is recommended by SFDC product management.

[Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZTv5AAG)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what profile settings are required to run this as I usually use an SA account, but it basically uses describe calls to pull out the information thand then uses [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) to format the information. See [SchemaSpy Org ERD](https://force201.wordpress.com/schemaspy-org%C2%A0erd/) for links.

Comment: It required API User privileges. I tried it on a behind proxy corporate network. It also requires graphwiz and Apache ant and JDBC driver. It's somewhat difficult to setup for someone who had never used ant and command line and is behind a proxy. However it's a really good tool and gives detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

There are some third party tools that might help.   Safyr from Silwood Technology uses the SFDC Metadata API to access the Objects in an Org and can then present the objects in Data Model form in a number of different formats.

I believe Grandite Silverun also has some kind of capability that gives data models